# $A_1,...A_n\;$ are independent events iff $A_1,...A_{n-1},A_{n}^{c}\;$ are independent events

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I know that if $A_1,...A_n\;$ are independent events, then we have forall $I\subseteq[n]\;$ $P(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}P(A_{i})$

I am kind of stuck, I guess I should be using de morgans laws or something of that sort.

Would love to get some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are independent. Then:

$$\Pr(A\cap B^c)=\Pr(B^c \vert A)\Pr(A)=(1-\Pr(B\vert A))\Pr(A)=(1-\Pr(B))\Pr(A)=\Pr(B^c)\Pr(A) $$

So for $n=2$ this is not a problem. For $n>2$, for each $I$ that contains $n$, you can denote $B=A_n$ and $A=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I\setminus \{n\} A_i} $ and use the above argument.